# Insert character in middle of string

Tags: sed, text-formatting

I would like to perform adding hyphen "-" character in my string.

How would like to perform?

```
vol0802-f522-6cc63-0a3-d
```

I am getting the above about output. However, I need the following output.

```
vol-0802f5226cc630a3d
```

I can add the missing `-` using

```
sed 's/\(.\{3\}\)/&-/;'
```

But the above command keeps the other `-` symbols unchanged.

Comment: What are the requirements for this? Please describe _why_ the input gets transformed into the output.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash 4+`, this works:

```bash
String='vol0802-f522-6cc63-0a3-d'
String=${String//-}
echo ${String}
vol0802f5226cc630a3d
String="${String:0:3}-${String:3}"
echo ${String}
vol-0802f5226cc630a3d
```

You didn't say if you always need the `-` at the third position, but that's easy enough to deal with.
If this isn't assistive, let us know what your environment is.
TY!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo "vol0802-f522-6cc63-0a3-d" | sed 's/-//g;s/[^0-9]*/&-/'
vol-0802f5226cc630a3d
```

Comment: You're assuming the first character after `vol` is decimal digit, that could just be a fluke of the input,  all the other digits appear to be hex.

Comment: @bxm You used my solution then downvoted with no way of me to change as you used the alternative. Classy!

Answer (score 0):

This should perform as described for the input provided:

```
sed 's/-//g;s/^.\{3\}/&-/'
```

As should this:

```
sed 's/-//g;s/^vol/&-/'
```